# String or binary data would be truncated when I insert data to a Newly created table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created a table

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[DimRegion2013]') AND type in (N'U'))
DROP TABLE [DimRegion2013]
Go
Create Table DimRegion2013

(RegionKey int NOT NULL identity Primary Key,                              
RegionView  char(1),
RegionViewCode  char(1),
SublocationString   nvarchar(7),
SubLocationCode char(10),
LocationCode    char(10),
RegionCode  char(10),
RegionGrpCode   char(10),
DivisionCode    char(10),
DivisionGrpCode char(10),
SubLocationDescription  char(50),
LocationDescription char(50),
RegionDescription   char(50),
RegionGrpDescription    char(50),
DivisionDescription char(50),
DivisionGrpDescription  char(50))
```

and then I tried to insert data into the DimRegion2013 table.

```
Select
'Region1' as RegionView,
'R1' as RegionViewCode,
sl.sublocationstring, 
sl.subLocationCode, 
l.locationcode,
r.regioncode,
rg.RegionGrpCode,
d.DivisionCode,
dg.DivisionGrpCode,
sl.SubLocationDescription, 
l.LocationDescription,
r.regiondescription,
rg.RegionGrpDescription,
d.divisionDescription,
dg.DivisionGrpDescription
from SMECSubLocation sl, 
SCLocation l, 
SCRegion r, 
SCRegionGrp rg,
SCDivision d,
SCDivisionGrp dg
where l.LocationCode = sl.LocationCode
and r.RegionCode = l.RegionCode
and r.RegionGrpCode = rg.RegionGrpCode
and d.divisioncode = rg.divisioncode
and d.divisiongrpcode = dg.divisiongrpcode
```

and I get this error

> Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 4
>   String or binary data would be truncated.

I don't see anything wrong with it. Please help me resolve this.

Thank you!

Beau

Comment: You are inserting the 7 character string literal `Region1` into a `char(1)` column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your table defines both

```
RegionView  char(1),
RegionViewCode  char(1)
```

but your are trying to insert

```
'Region1' as RegionView,
'R1' as RegionViewCode
```

which is too much to fit in those fields. You need to make the fields larger to hold that data. If the data varies a lot in size I'd use `varchar(??)`where ?? is the maximum expected length of the strings you want to store (like `varchar(20)`if 20 is the maximum.)

It might of course be possible that some other field is getting truncated too, but without knowing the definitions of the other tables that you are using it's impossible to say for sure.

Comment: @BA82283 Happy to help. On a side note you might want to use the `varchar`type instead of `char`if the data you are inserting varies in length as `char`uses up all space allocated for it which might lead to a lot of wasted storage.